# How to retrieve a set of member objects using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

This question is to follow up with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688126/how-to-retrieve-a-complex-class-and-its-members-using-hibernate-projection). I need to retrieve a list of complex classes. Each has a few sets in it and just a specific number of them should be retrieved. I've already read answers of these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730411/map-hibernate-projections-result-to-java-pojo-model),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993000/how-to-retrieve-a-member-object-of-a-class-using-hibernate) but none of them solved my issue.

I need to find a list of students that are in a specific group and located in a specific location, and their phone numbers in their address. I also need to show distance of each student to a specific coordinate.

Following code works fine, the only issue is I can not retrieve list of objects for example list of emails, list of groups and list of phones of each student.

```
@Entity
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -23949494858373847L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    String id;
    String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_groups", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);
    ..
}


@Entity
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -274634747474623637L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    String addId;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "locId", nullable = false)
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String address;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "phoneOwner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();


        String formula = "( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians("
                + lat
                + ") ) * cos( radians( this_.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( this_.longitude ) - radians("
                + lan + ") ) +" + "sin ( radians(" + lat
                + ") ) * sin( radians( this_.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance";
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ProjectionList pl = Projections
                .projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("std.id").as("id"))
                .add(Projections.property("std.name").as("name"))
                .add(Projections.property("addr.address").as(
                        "address"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.name").as("location"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.city").as("city"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.latitude").as("latitude"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.longitude").as("longitude"))
                .add(Projections.sqlProjection(formula,
                        new String[] { "distance" },
                        new Type[] { new DoubleType() }));

        List<Students> students = (List<Students) session
                .createCriteria(Address.class, "addr")
                .createAlias("addr.student", "std")
                .createAlias("std.groups", "group")
                .createAlias("addr.location", "location")
                .setProjection(pl)
                .setFetchMode("group", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .add(Restrictions.ilike("group.name", groupName))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("location.id", locId))
                .setResultTransformer(
                        new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Students.class))
                .list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default class of hibernate does not transfer nested objects, if you have performance issue you should try following code.

Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer) and [this one](http://quabr.com/20331852/java-hibernate-transformer-aliastobeannestedresulttransformer) that is improved version of that.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor;
import org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessorFactory;
import org.hibernate.property.Setter;
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer;
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer;
import org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer;

/**
 * Help to transform alises with nested alises
 * 
 * @author Miguel Resendiz
 * 
 */
public class AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer extends
AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8047276133980128266L;

    private static final int TUPE_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int ALISES_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int FIELDNAME_INDEX = 2;

    private static final PropertyAccessor accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory
            .getPropertyAccessor("property");

    private final Class<?> resultClass;

    private Object[] entityTuples;
    private String[] entityAliases;

    private Map<String, Class<?>> fieldToClass = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    private Map<String, List<?>> subEntities = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    private List<String> nestedAliases = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, Class<?>> listFields = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases,
            int tupleLength) {
        return false;
    }

    public AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(Class<?> resultClass) {

        this.resultClass = resultClass;
    }

    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {

        handleSubEntities(tuple, aliases);
        cleanParams(tuple, aliases);
        ResultTransformer rootTransformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(
                resultClass);
        Object root = rootTransformer.transformTuple(entityTuples,
                entityAliases);

        loadSubEntities(root);

        cleanMaps();
        return root;
    }

    private void handleSubEntities(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases)
            throws HibernateException {
        String fieldName = "";
        String aliasName = "";
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
                String alias = aliases[i];
                if (alias.contains(".")) {

                    String[] sp = alias.split("\\.");
                    StringBuilder aliasBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int j = 0; j < sp.length; j++) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            fieldName = sp[j];
                        } else {
                            aliasBuilder.append(sp[j]);
                            aliasBuilder.append(".");
                        }
                    }
                    aliasName = aliasBuilder.substring(0,
                            aliasBuilder.length() - 1);

                    nestedAliases.add(alias);
                    manageEntities(fieldName, aliasName, tuple[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not instantiate resultclass: "
                    + resultClass.getName() + " for field name: " + fieldName
                    + " and alias name:" + aliasName);
        }
    }

    private Class<?> findClass(String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException,
    SecurityException {
        if (fieldToClass.containsKey(fieldName)) {
            return fieldToClass.get(fieldName);
        } else {
            Class<?> subclass = resultClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
                    .getType();

            if (subclass.equals(List.class) || subclass.equals(Set.class)) {
                if (subclass.equals(List.class)) {
                    listFields.put(fieldName, LinkedList.class);
                } else {
                    listFields.put(fieldName, HashSet.class);
                }
                Field field = resultClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                ParameterizedType genericType = (ParameterizedType) field
                        .getGenericType();
                subclass = (Class<?>) genericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

            }
            fieldToClass.put(fieldName, subclass);
            return subclass;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void manageEntities(String fieldName, String aliasName,
            Object tupleValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Class<?> subclass = findClass(fieldName);
        if (!subEntities.containsKey(fieldName)) {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
            list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            list.add(FIELDNAME_INDEX, subclass);
            subEntities.put(fieldName, list);
        }
        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(TUPE_INDEX))
        .add(tupleValue);
        ((List<String>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(ALISES_INDEX))
        .add(aliasName);
    }

    private void cleanParams(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        entityTuples = new Object[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];
        entityAliases = new String[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];

        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < aliases.length; j++) {
            if (!nestedAliases.contains(aliases[j])) {
                entityTuples[i] = tuple[j];
                entityAliases[i] = aliases[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private void loadSubEntities(Object root) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            for (String fieldName : subEntities.keySet()) {
                Class<?> subclass = (Class<?>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(
                        FIELDNAME_INDEX);

                ResultTransformer subclassTransformer = new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(
                        subclass);

                Object subObject = subclassTransformer.transformTuple(
                        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(0))
                        .toArray(),
                        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(1))
                        .toArray(new String[0]));

                Setter setter = accessor.getSetter(resultClass, fieldName);
                if (listFields.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                    Class<?> collectionClass = listFields.get(fieldName);
                    Collection subObjectList = (Collection) collectionClass
                            .newInstance();
                    subObjectList.add(subObject);
                    setter.set(root, subObjectList, null);
                } else {
                    setter.set(root, subObject, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }
    }

    private void cleanMaps() {
        fieldToClass = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        subEntities = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
        nestedAliases = new ArrayList<String>();
        listFields = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please have a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554572/illegalargumentexception-occurred-while-calling-setter-for-property-expected-ty

Answer (score 10):

That's a good question. I have faced similar issue. So AliasToBeanResultTransformer only transforms main object as entity but it doesn't have the capability to select nested object as nested object.

To get nested object, we should use Custom Transformer. Here is an example:

https://github.com/madhupathy/Hibernate-Custom-Transformer

I avoid projections in such cases and fetch all objects to keep it simple, if there is no huge performance impact and I need almost all values.

Comment: Please have a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554572/illegalargumentexception-occurred-while-calling-setter-for-property-expected-ty