# How to group by projections with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I need to find a list of students that are in a specific group and located in a specific address along with their phone numbers in their location.

My main issue is I can not retrieve phone numbers of each student as a collection. For example if I have student1,student2. Phone 1111 for student1 in location1 and phone 2222 and phone 3333 for student2 in location 1 and phone 444 for student2 in location2.

*Lets say I have*

```
Student1 Alex group1 1111 Location1 Street1
Student3 Jack group1 93939 Location2 Street4
Student7 Joe group2 22223 Location4 Street8
Student2 John group1 2222 3333 Location1 Street1
Student2 John group1 4444 Location1 Street2
Student12 Mark group1 4423 Location9 Street9
```

**Sample Output with data**

```
 User asks for all students in group1 and location1 

Student1 Alex Street1 phone 1111 distance30
Student2 John Street1 phones 22222,3333 distance30
Student2 John Street2 phone 4444 distance40
```

***In other words, I would like to have a list of students along with their locations and phones of the selected location.***

Hibernate returns following error message against my current code

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: 
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property 
[com.example.Address.phones (expected type = java.util.List)]; target 
= [com.example.results.AllStudents@6deeac0], property value = 
[11111111] setter of com.example.results.AllStudents.phones; nested 
exception is IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter 
for property [com.example.results.AllStudents.phones (expected type = 
java.util.List)]; target = [com.example.results.AllStudents@6deeac0], 
property value = [11111111]
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -23949494858373847L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    String id;
    String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_groups", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);
    ..
}
```

**Address**

```
@Entity
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -274634747474623637L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    String addId;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "locId", nullable = false)
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String address;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "phoneOwner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();


        String formula = "( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians("
                + lat
                + ") ) * cos( radians( this_.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( this_.longitude ) - radians("
                + lan + ") ) +" + "sin ( radians(" + lat
                + ") ) * sin( radians( this_.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance";
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ProjectionList pl = Projections
                .projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("std.id").as("id"))
                .add(Projections.property("std.name").as("name"))
                .add(Projections.property("addr.address").as(
                        "address"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.name").as("location"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.city").as("city"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.latitude").as("latitude"))
                .add(Projections.property("location.longitude").as("longitude"))
                .add(Projections.sqlProjection(formula,
                        new String[] { "distance" },
                        new Type[] { new DoubleType() }));

        List<AllStudents> students = (List<AllStudents) session
                .createCriteria(Address.class, "addr")
                .createAlias("addr.student", "std")
                .createAlias("std.groups", "group")
                .createAlias("addr.location", "location")
                .setProjection(pl)
                .setFetchMode("group", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .add(Restrictions.ilike("group.name", groupName))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("location.id", locId))
                .setResultTransformer(
                        new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(AllStudents.class))
                .list();
```

**Results class**

```
public class AllStudents {
   List<String> phones;
   ...
}
```

**AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer**

```
public class AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer extends
AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8047276133980128266L;

    private static final int TUPE_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int ALISES_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int FIELDNAME_INDEX = 2;

    private static final PropertyAccessor accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory
            .getPropertyAccessor("property");

    private final Class<?> resultClass;

    private Object[] entityTuples;
    private String[] entityAliases;

    private Map<String, Class<?>> fieldToClass = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    private Map<String, List<?>> subEntities = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    private List<String> nestedAliases = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, Class<?>> listFields = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases,
            int tupleLength) {
        return false;
    }

    public AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(Class<?> resultClass) {

        this.resultClass = resultClass;
    }

    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {

        handleSubEntities(tuple, aliases);
        cleanParams(tuple, aliases);
        ResultTransformer rootTransformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(
                resultClass);
        Object root = rootTransformer.transformTuple(entityTuples,
                entityAliases);

        loadSubEntities(root);

        cleanMaps();
        return root;
    }

    private void handleSubEntities(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases)
            throws HibernateException {
        String fieldName = "";
        String aliasName = "";
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
                String alias = aliases[i];
                if (alias.contains(".")) {

                    String[] sp = alias.split("\\.");
                    StringBuilder aliasBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int j = 0; j < sp.length; j++) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            fieldName = sp[j];
                        } else {
                            aliasBuilder.append(sp[j]);
                            aliasBuilder.append(".");
                        }
                    }
                    aliasName = aliasBuilder.substring(0,
                            aliasBuilder.length() - 1);

                    nestedAliases.add(alias);
                    manageEntities(fieldName, aliasName, tuple[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not instantiate resultclass: "
                    + resultClass.getName() + " for field name: " + fieldName
                    + " and alias name:" + aliasName);
        }
    }

    private Class<?> findClass(String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException,
    SecurityException {
        if (fieldToClass.containsKey(fieldName)) {
            return fieldToClass.get(fieldName);
        } else {
            Class<?> subclass = resultClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
                    .getType();

            if (subclass.equals(List.class) || subclass.equals(Set.class)) {
                if (subclass.equals(List.class)) {
                    listFields.put(fieldName, LinkedList.class);
                } else {
                    listFields.put(fieldName, HashSet.class);
                }
                Field field = resultClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                ParameterizedType genericType = (ParameterizedType) field
                        .getGenericType();
                subclass = (Class<?>) genericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

            }
            fieldToClass.put(fieldName, subclass);
            return subclass;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void manageEntities(String fieldName, String aliasName,
            Object tupleValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Class<?> subclass = findClass(fieldName);
        if (!subEntities.containsKey(fieldName)) {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
            list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            list.add(FIELDNAME_INDEX, subclass);
            subEntities.put(fieldName, list);
        }
        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(TUPE_INDEX))
        .add(tupleValue);
        ((List<String>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(ALISES_INDEX))
        .add(aliasName);
    }

    private void cleanParams(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        entityTuples = new Object[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];
        entityAliases = new String[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];

        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < aliases.length; j++) {
            if (!nestedAliases.contains(aliases[j])) {
                entityTuples[i] = tuple[j];
                entityAliases[i] = aliases[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private void loadSubEntities(Object root) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            for (String fieldName : subEntities.keySet()) {
                Class<?> subclass = (Class<?>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(
                        FIELDNAME_INDEX);

                ResultTransformer subclassTransformer = new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(
                        subclass);

                Object subObject = subclassTransformer.transformTuple(
                        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(0))
                        .toArray(),
                        ((List<Object>) subEntities.get(fieldName).get(1))
                        .toArray(new String[0]));

                Setter setter = accessor.getSetter(resultClass, fieldName);
                if (listFields.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                    Class<?> collectionClass = listFields.get(fieldName);
                    Collection subObjectList = (Collection) collectionClass
                            .newInstance();
                    subObjectList.add(subObject);
                    setter.set(root, subObjectList, null);
                } else {
                    setter.set(root, subObject, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }
    }

    private void cleanMaps() {
        fieldToClass = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        subEntities = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
        nestedAliases = new ArrayList<String>();
        listFields = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer](https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer/blob/master/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer.java) supports nested DTOs but it doesn not support Collections of DTOs.

You can change the `AllStudent` DTS to:

```
public class AllStudents {
    Student student;
    String phone;
    Location location;

    public AllStudents(Student student, String phone, Location location) {
        this.student = student;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

and you need to add a `StudentDTO` to hold the aggregation result:

```
public class StudentDTO {
    private final Student student;
    private String location;
    private List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public StudentDTO(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public List<String> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }
}
```

Now when you run your query you get a List of AllStudents:

```
List<AllStudents> allStudents = ...
```

which you simply group like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Long, StudentDTO> studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(AllStudents all : allStudents) {
    StudentDTO studentDTO = studentMap.get(all.getStudent().getId());
    if(studentDTO == null) {
        studentDTO = new StudentDTO(all.getStudent());
        studentMap.put(all.getStudent().getId(), studentDTO);
    }
    if(all.getPhone() != null) {
        studentDTO.getPhones().add(all.getPhone());
    }
    studentDTO.setLocation(all.getLocation());
}

List<StudentDTO> studentDTOs = new ArrayList<>(studentMap.values());
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you got me wrong. I do not want to have a map of students with their phones. I just want to have a collection of student objects and a list of phones of each person in his/her respective object. Question is updated. Really sorry for any inconvenience