# Are PropertyAccessor and PropertyAccessorFactory removed or deprecated?

Tags: hibernate, orm

In the issue 29980421, I found that the code example in the answer include PropertyAccessor and PropertyAccessorFactory. When I check the hibernate-orm project, I found that these classes have been deleted:

org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor was deleted at 2015-06-04 15:12:17 GMT-04:00 
org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessorFactory was    deleted at 2015-06-04 15:12:17 GMT-04:00

Would anyone give any feedback on this?

If possible, would you provide a running example, replacing the code example in the first answer of In the issue 29980421?
[How to retrieve a set of member objects using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980421/how-to-retireve-a-set-member-objects-using-hibernate)

**Edit:**

Thank you for your comment. After reading the comment, I removed hibernate 4.x from the question. How about PropertyAccessorFactory?

Comment: In Hibernate _4.x_ the `PropertyAccessor` does still exist. You've checked the _master_ (or _5.x_) branch. And in master it was simply replaced by `org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessStrategy`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too late, but now you must choose one of the PropertyAccessStrategy implementations, like PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.

```
    PropertyAccessStrategy accessor = PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.INSTANCE;
    PropertyAccess access = accessor.buildPropertyAccess(entityClass, "propertyName");
```